# Zend: How can I globally set the current navigation item?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-navigation

### config:

```
resources.frontController.plugins.nav = "WD_Controller_Plugin_Nav"
```

### bootstrap:

```
protected function _initAutoloader() {
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$loader->registerNamespace('WD_');
return $loader;
}

protected function _initNav() {
  $this->bootstrap('layout');
  $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
  $view = $layout->getView();
  $config = new Zend_Config_Xml( APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml', 'nav');
  $navigation = Zend_Navigation( $config );

  $fc = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
  $fc->registerPlugin( new WD_Controller_Plugin_Nav() );
  $view->navigation( $navigation );
}
```

### library/WD/Controller/Plugin/Nav.php:

```
class WD_Controller_Plugin_Nav extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {

    public function postDispatch() {
        $uri = $this->_request->getPathInfo();
            $view = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView();
        $activeNav = $view->navigation()->findByUri($uri)->setActive(true);
    }
}
```

### web output:

> Uncaught exception
>   'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception'
>   with message 'Plugin by name
>   'FindByUri' was not found in the
>   registry

I pretty much know what I'm doing wrong, in that I'm referencing the Zend View Helper Navigation and not the Navigation directly ( findByUri method exists in Zend_Navigation directly ), but I'm not sure how to properly reference it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller plugins do not have a reference to the view object by default, like Controllers do.  There are plenty of different ways to grab your view instance.

One, via the ViewRenderer action helper, like so:

```
$view = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer')->view;
```

Two, from your layout:

```
$view = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView();
```

Or, as always, from your application bootstrap. But that will depend on how you set it up.

Once you do that, there is a `getContainer()` method available to you on *all* Navigation view helpers. So,

```
$container = $view->navigation()->getContainer();
```

Should work for you,

Comment: Ack silly me - +1 and I apologize but I already had figured this out.. I accidentally used my previous pastebin when I should have used my updated pastebin. Basically, I have a reference to view, but since I'm referencing the view helper nav and not the real nav, I can't properly invoke findByUri.. not sure how to reference the real nav object.